# How Do I Parse A Python Tuple To Print Each Value On New Line?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

Assuming I have a Python dictionary like so:

```
GroupName [('G:', 'G:/path/to/folder1', 'Full Access'), ('G:', 'G:/path/to/folder2', 'Full Access'), ('G:', 'G:/path/to/folder3', 'Full Access')]
```

How do I loop through it to print each entry on a new line like so:

```
GroupName G:/path/to/folder1 Full Access
GroupName G:/path/to/folder2 Full Access
GroupName G:/path/to/folder3 Full Access
```

I know that you can do

```
for k,v in GroupName.items:
    print k,v
```

which results in

```
GroupName [('G:', 'G:/path/to/folder1', 'Full Access'), ('G:', 'G:/path/to/folder2', 'Full Access'), ('G:', 'G:/path/to/folder3', 'Full Access')]
```

But I am unsure how to further parse v to print the values individually.

Assistance would be appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: That's not a dictionary. Dictionaries have curly brackets and colons.

Comment: @ChrisC what `type` is GroupSearch?

Comment: @af3ld It is type dict

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print a list of tuples. You probably want to do something like

```
for e in GroupName:
    print("GroupName " + e[1] + " " + e[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you aren't dealing with a dictionary, there are no key value pairs here. What you have is a list of tuples: there are two different data types present. You will need to iterate through the list of groups, and deal with the values of each group tuple.

This produces your desired result:

```
group_name = [('G:', 'G:/path/to/folder1', 'Full Access'), ('G:', 'G:/path/to/folder2', 'Full Access'), ('G:', 'G:/path/to/folder3', 'Full Access')]

for group in group_name:
    print(*(group_property for group_property in group))
```

This loops through the list with `for group in group_name` and unpacks and prints the tuple that makes up each element in the list, using `print(*(group_property for group_property in group))`

Comment: I tried this and it returned multiple rows that look like this: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x00000000067C5510>

Comment: Actually they are key-value pairs. If you look at my first code snippet, GroupName is the key and the folder info is the values. I verified this with for k,v in GroupSearch print k,v

Comment: Your first code snippet does not show a dictionary, it shows a class name (which I assume is an unconventially named variable) followed by a space, followed by a list. Dictionaries are defined using `{key: value}` in python. I think more clarification is needed on what you are trying to do before I can properly answer this question.